# Deploy the same JS Link for multiple views across libraries

Tags: 2013, javascript, document-library, jslink, view-styles

I need to use the js for all views in all libraries in a site.  Is there a way to deploy this in one hit rather than editing each view individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use powershell:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://mysite
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists["List Name"]
$wp = $list.RootFolder.Name + "/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
$wpManager = $website.GetLimitedWebPartManager($wp, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$webpart = $wpManager.WebParts[0]
$webpart.JSLink = "~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/myScript.js"
$wpManager.SaveChanges($webpart)
```

You can loop throught your lists to add the js script.

Comment: Thanks how do I specify a specific site?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I am getting these errors You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. Cannot index into a null array. The property 'JSLink' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists and can be set.
Any ideas?

Comment: The `$webpart` is null execute the script line for line to check if you retrive the right object

Answer (score 1):

Change $website to $web , the final script will look like below :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepointsite
$list = $web.Lists["TestJSLink"]
$wp = $list.RootFolder.Name + "/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
$wpManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($wp, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$webpart = $wpManager.WebParts[0]
$webpart.JSLink = "~layouts/XYZ/JSLink.js"
$wpManager.SaveChanges($webpart)
Write-Output "Done"
```